# manually choosing best 802.11ac wifi channel in 5 GHz band

Tags: wireless-networking

Can someone explain, and provide answer to the following:

**Background:**

- have Xfinity service with DPC3941T wireless router.
- environment is suburbs; each 1 family house is on 0.25 acre lot up & down the street, and about 0.5 acre separation between my street and parallel street.
- channel rating from wifi analyzer for 2.4 ghz band says *None, try alternative WiFi Band 5 GHz.*
- I have disabled my 2.4 ghz wifi and want to run best channel in 5 GHz band.

**Using WiFiAnalyzer for 5GHz band**:

- shows channels 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140, 144, 149,153,157,161, 165.
- channels 36, 40, 44, 48 each show an access point count of 11 at < -85 dBm.
- channels 149, 153 show an access point count of 1 each, not sure why.
- rest of channels show 0 access point count
- says best channels are: 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124...

**On My Xfinity provided DPC3941T router for 5 GHz band:**

- I only have these channels to manually choose from: 36, 40, 44, 48, 149, 153, 157, 161, 165
- Channel bandwidth choice of 20, or 20/40, or 20/40/80.
- The three choices of channel bandwidth does not changes what is offered for manual channel choices.

If I leave channel selection on automatic, the DPC3941T chooses channel 36.  Is this good or bad?  Should I use that or can I do better by choosing a channel manually and if so then which?  Please elaborate on the reason why, given this scenario, to help one understand *how to choose a best channel for 802.11ac wifi at 5 GHz band*.  Thanks.

Comment: Honestly I would lean towards buying a Wireless access point or router for more channel options if you are worried about interference. Or leave it on a channel with the least amount of APs

Comment: my understanding (someone correct me if wrong) that because I have Xfinity that they have a *hidden* "xfinitywifi" that is always going that I cannot control.  I have looked at buying a new router but because I have phone landline bundled I am basically stuck with their provided router a DPC3941T.  But I am mainly interested in understanding these many 5ghz channels that are out there now with 802.11ac.

Comment: You can turn off that feature and set your router/modem to only be a modem and use one of the ethernet ports to your new router or acess point to provide the wifi. To turn off the xfinity wifi acess point that allows other with the service to connect through your router to use xfinity you need to go into your account online and toggle it off.